# Exact object to byte conversion, similar to memcpy in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, network-programming, cross-platform

I have been looking for a solution for this for a little while and non of the stuff I've found quite matches. It is great that C# has a built in serialization library but that is not quite what I am looking for. I need to serialize objects in such a way that I can serialize them, append header data to the packet ie. ID number, timestamp, object type etc. and then be able to send it out without having to keep in mind the platform I am sending it to. In other words, I should be able to unwrap my packet in C++ or in Java without much more knowledge than what object type I am casting into and the order of header data. The binary formatter in C# creates a problem because it is designed to be deserialized on the other end using the same library. It also creates bloated packets which I would rather not have to deal with. I would rather format my packet as such

|========|========|=========|===|==============|

| packetID | datatype | timeStamp | etc | serializedObject |

|========|========|=========|===|==============|

It would be nice if I had access to something along the lines of memcpy in order to achieve this because then  as long as the data type order of the object being deserialized into matches (Yes, assuming the other language has the same byte sizes for datatypes), it is easy to grab data from the server on a new platform (say I want to grab data of an Android (Java) or an iPhone (obj. C)) with little hassle

Comment: Why don't you use XML or JSON?

Comment: My understanding of using XML is that it adds a lot of bloat to the packets. Because the server acts as a central hub, large packets being served to a lot of devices while the server is doing other tasks can quickly create a lot of congestion. That's a good solution, but I am going to be running this off a pretty old machine so even a few clients can make a lot of work for it.

Comment: you could also use BSON or protobuf-net...

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Google's protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) to good effect. It's small, fast, cross platform, backwards compatible and serializes to a binary format. It doesn't support the custom header information you're looking for, but if you can frame your own packets you can tack a custom header onto the binary stream as you see fit. Protobuf can compile down into [C#](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/), iOS, Java and C++.

Comment: I cant seem to find the a C# variation of this. "using a variety of languages – Java, C++, or Python."

Comment: Jon Skeet wrote a port of it available here: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/ and Marc Gravel has a version here http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/

Comment: Is there a way to get the direct byte/binary representation of an object in the way it is being held in the RAM? Thanks for the links! Bit converter is supposed to do this but it adds a bunch of junk into it.

Comment: @user1260028 Not as far as I know. In regards to Protobuf, it encodes messages in its own binary format - more about that here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding.